# Dynamic Hyperlink Function to create a link for going from one cell to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In the below screenshot, you can see that I have the worksheet Name in A23 and cell address in B23.

Note: The Content of B23 is prepared by a Macro. So it is dynamic and might get changed every time.  However A23 (sheet Name) stays the same.

How can I use the Hyperlink function by clicking on it  to go from the cell C23 to the cell in worksheet "BW2018" and cell A353 ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GO to the insert tab and select on the link button. When the window pops up click on the "Place in This Document" button. In the space where it says "Type the cell reference:", do just that and you can link to whatever cell you want. [image]

If you want to create a dynamic hyperlink then you can use the formula suggested by @m. salem.  `=HYPERLINK(A2&B2&C2)` Where `A2` is the workbook name, `B2` is the worksheet name and `C2` is the cell that you want to link to.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do I type the address of worksheet in cell A23 and address of cell in cell B23? It Returns an error when I do it. Please see the screenshot which I posted. I would like to have this in Terms of the Excel function Hyperlink.

Comment: Type `$A$353` and select sheet BW2018. I do not know how to create a dynamic link that changes with the contents of cell B23.

Comment: You can also create a named range  and use that in case the data in the other worksheet gets moved or if the page is renamed.

Comment: Thanks for the correct English word. Yes, a dynamic link because the Content of B23 is created by a Macro and it changes every time.I just edited my Question.

Answer (score 0):

So, the below screenshot Shows how to use Hyperlink function dynamicly:

Please note that in this case, A1 is a not dynamic, but the sheet Name, for example Canada, is dynamic and can be changed every time.

[image]